# I want to open new screen, but without the putting the screen above the screen, is that possible in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I want to open a new screen in flutter app , but without the putting the screen above the screen I mean like any normal website routing pages with back button for previous page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

This will remove all the previous routes before pushing the new screen

If you want only remove the last page, then you can use this:

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushReplacementNamed('/login');
```

Comment: yes, right but I want only the previous route not all the routes

Comment: Then use `pushReplacement` or `pushReplacementNamed` @NoorEddinHasan

Comment: @NoorEddinHasan check edited answer